# How to timeout members with a bot if they swear too much in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am working on a basic Discord bot using `node.js` and `discord.js`. Basically I have the following code to block swear words:

```js
const user = message.author;
    var _0x2d55 = ["\x66\x75\x63\x6B", "\x64\x69\x63\x6B", "\x61\x73\x73", "\x62\x69\x74\x63\x68", "\x77\x61\x6E\x6B", "\x70\x75\x73\x73\x79", "\x63\x75\x6E\x74", "\x6E\x69\x67\x67\x65\x72", "\x6E\x69\x67\x67\x61", "\x74\x69\x74\x74\x69\x65\x73", "\x74\x69\x64\x64\x69\x65\x73", "\x63\x6F\x63\x6B", "\x62\x6F\x6E\x65\x72", "\x63\x75\x6D", "\x62\x75\x6D", "\x73\x65\x78", "\x7A\x68\x61\x74\x75", "\x7A\x61\x76\x61\x64\x79\x61", "\x6C\x61\x75\x64\x79\x61", "\x6C\x61\x76\x64\x79\x61", "\x62\x6F\x6F\x62", "\x70\x65\x6E\x69\x73", "\x76\x61\x67\x69\x6E\x61", "\x67\x61\x6E\x64", "\x63\x68\x6F\x74", "\x63\x68\x75\x74", "\x62\x68\x6F\x73\x61\x64", "\x70\x6F\x72\x6E", "\x63\x69\x62\x61\x69", "\x73\x74\x66\x75", "\x77\x74\x66", "\x77\x68\x6F\x72\x65", "\x76\x69\x72\x67\x69\x6E", "\x62\x75\x74\x74", "\x73\x75\x63\x6B\x65\x72", "\x61\x6E\x61\x6C", "\uD83D\uDD95"];
    let blacklisted = [_0x2d55[0], _0x2d55[1], _0x2d55[2], _0x2d55[3], _0x2d55[4], _0x2d55[5], _0x2d55[6], _0x2d55[7], _0x2d55[8], _0x2d55[9], _0x2d55[10], _0x2d55[11], _0x2d55[12], _0x2d55[13], _0x2d55[14], _0x2d55[15], _0x2d55[16], _0x2d55[17], _0x2d55[18], _0x2d55[19], _0x2d55[20], _0x2d55[21], _0x2d55[22], _0x2d55[23], _0x2d55[24], _0x2d55[25], _0x2d55[26], _0x2d55[27], _0x2d55[28], _0x2d55[29], _0x2d55[30], _0x2d55[31], _0x2d55[32], _0x2d55[33], _0x2d55[34], _0x2d55[35], _0x2d55[36]]
    let foundInText = false;
    for(var i in blacklisted) {
        if(message.content.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, "").replace(/ /g, "").includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
    }
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('pass') || message.content.toLowerCase().includes('g and')) foundInText = false;
    if(foundInText === true && message.channel.type !== 'DM') {
        message.delete().catch(error => message.channel.send("Heck! I couldn't work as intended because of: `" + ` ${error}` + ": Manage Messages `."));
        if(message.author.id !== client.user.id) {
            message.channel.send(`${user} You can't send that here!`);
        }
        if(!message.author.bot) {
            message.author.send(`You can be banned for using bad or profane words or emojis on servers. Don\'t use them, ever!`);
        }
    }
```

I want to go a step ahead and timeout members that swear let's say 10 times. How can I achieve that? Please help. Also I am not a pro in javascript!

Answer (score 1):

You should  save somewhere the number of times each user says a bad word and then check that value every time you update it.In database for example , a relation of type <user,channel,bad-words-count>.

Comment: Can you please show an example implementing in my code. I am really new to this! Sry!